# Change default rule type in SonarQube 6.4

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to change the type for rules existing in SonarQube 6.4 (not custom rules). For example, can I change an existing rule from a bug to a vulnerability or a code smell etc.. ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may try something: develop a simple plugin which overrides the concerned rules.

Comment: Thnks, it sounds a good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, rule type is not settable, although as @Simon pointed out, you can change the type of an issue.

Comment: @SabrinaS however note that the rule type can be changed on an issue, so for example a vulnerability can be considered as a code smell in a special context.

Answer (score -1):

Good question SabrinaS... It is needed to change type of rules existing in SonarQube 6.4 .

Comment: Thank you Asmi   :)